# inDesign endnotes in book

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am working on a book file containg 12 chapters (saved as individual files and added to book file). I need to add endnotes at the end of the book (as, let's say chapter 13).
Adobe CC update 2018 included creation and adding of endnotes in inDesign in orderly fashion, but I can't seem to be able to use them on separate file at the end of my book. Instead it only lets me create it at the end of individual chapters. I tried to move the endnotes frame to separate file, but then it loses its connections to the pointed endnotes.

Is there a way (other than doing it manually, which I really wanted to avoid) to add endnotes to the end of the book, instead of a chapter?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the new Endnotes feature isn't well supported while working in a book. It's a version 1, and hopefully this could be improved in the future.
I suggest you fill out a request form here: https://indesign.uservoice.com/forums/601021-adobe-indesign-feature-suggestions

Meanwhile, you may want to have a look at Peter Kahrel's script: http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/end-of-book_notes.html
Haven't tested it, but looks promising. If you try it out, feedback would be great.